# RestKit object mapping with foreign keys and services

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to set up a RestKit object mapping for a rest-like service over what I unfortunately have no control.

The model is a wish list with with a list of products. The WishList and the Product has obviously many-to-many relation. The wish list and the product has various attributes, for simplicity let's suppose that they both have only name.

I have separate services to get the details a wish list, the details of the product, and the relationship between them.

For example:

**GET /api/wish_list/?id=1234**

```
{ 
    "name"="My wish list",
    "id"=1234
}
```

**GET /api/products**

```
{
    products:[
    {
        "name"="Product 1",
        "id"=1111
    },
    {
        "name"="Product 2",
        "id"=2222
    },
    {
        "name"="Product 3",
        "id"=3333
    }]
}
```

**GET /api/wish_list_products/?wish_list_id=1234**

```
{
    products:[
    {
        "id"=1111
    },
    {
        "id"=2222
    }
}
```

I created the core data relationship between the Product and WishList entities but how could I tell to RestKit the fact that it should make a second request to fetch the list of the IDs of the products for a particular WishList?

I guess I should use `[RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:objectClass:pathPattern:method:]` and/or `RKConnectionDescription` object, but I really could not figure out from the help how they could help me in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RestKit won't automatically load the data for the relationship, you need to tell it when to do so. If you add the route using `routeWithRelationshipName:objectClass:pathPattern:method:` then you can make the request using `getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:ofObject:parameters:success:failure:`. Basically it makes linking the relationship name to the request to gather the required details.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I supposed that RestKit will load automatically the data. I managed to get `getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:ofObject:parameters:success:failure:` working, but it seems to me that it simply fetches the objects and does not create the relationship with the source object. Do I have to create also the association manually?

Comment: It should populate the relationship too, it has the source object and the name of the relationship. Did you check the (trace) log for the mapping to see if it indicates any issues?

Comment: I checked carefully the trace log but did not find anything suspicious: RestKit simply does not try to create these relationship. However I can create them quite easily in the success block of the operation that fetches the child objects.